# Can Not Find Header File in Xcode

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing

I'm trying to use the objective-c-html-parser to parse html string in Xcode 4.3.2. The following url is the instruction about how to config it. But I still get the error "libxml/HTMLparser.h" file not found. Can someone know how to resolve this issue?

objective-c-html-parser instruction: https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

Comment: and are you including libxml and it's header files in your project?

Comment: Thanks Michael for your quick response. I have already included it. I got the error when compiling.  # In the project settings add "/usr/include/libxml2" to the "header search paths" field
# Ctrl Click the Frameworks group choose Add -> Existing Frameworks and from the list choose libxml2.dylib

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this `"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"` in your `header search paths` and it will solve your problem!